# Initialize derived class with base class

Tags: class, kotlin

Is there a built-in method in Kotlin to do this?

```
open class Base {
    var data: Int = 0
}

class Derived(arg: Base) : Base() {
    init {
        copyAllProperties(from = arg, to = this)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write it yourself:

```
open class Base() {
    var data: Int = 0
}

class Derived(arg: Base) : Base() {
    init {
        super.data = arg.data
    }
}
```

Or use `implementation by delegation`[[1]](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html#implementation-by-delegation):

```
interface Base {
    var data: Int
}

class BaseImpl : Base {
    override var data: Int = 0
}

class Derived(b: Base) : Base by b
```

Answer (score 0):

So there is no Kotlin built-in that acts like a copy constructor.
Implementation by delegation looks like overkill.
I personally prefer to just write copy constructor by myself:

```
open class Base() {
    var data: Int = 0

    constructor(arg: Base) : this() {
        data = arg.data
    }
}

class Derived(arg: Base) : Base(arg) {}
```